# Сглаживание волны

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, числа

Приветствую, коллеги.

На входе имеется переменного размера массив чисел (прошу рассматривать как волну — график). Задача состоит в том, чтобы сделать упрощенный «шаблон» для того, чтобы можно было сравнивать его с другим похожим массивом (волну, схожую с шаблоном волны). Упрощение самих чисел очень простое — я просто понижаю «размерность» самих чисел:

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    arr[i] = round(arr[i] / 5) * 5;
```

Массив:

```
[7, -5, 3, 0, 12, 10]
```

...становится таким:

```
[5, -5, 5, 0, 10, 10]
```

Но вот сравнение должно проходить нормально при разных размерах массивов. То есть, кроме упрощения нужно входящий массив привести к длине шаблона, с которым будет происходить сравнивание. Допустим, размер массива-шаблона — 3. Значит, и входящий массив нужно привести к этому размеру:

```
[ (7-5)/2, (3+0)/2, (12+10)/2 ]  =>  [1, 2, 11]
```

Тут я просто рассчитал среднее арифметическое двух соседних элементов, здесь всего лишь простой пример. Но вот как быть в ситуациях, когда массив нужно растянуть? Или в ситуациях, когда размер входящего массива — 15, а привести нужно к массиву размера 10? Как быть, подскажите?

На ум приходит, что можно использовать какой-нибудь алгоритм сглаживания изображений, но я ничего не понял, к примеру, об алгоритме Lanczos. Поэтому и прошу помощи, быть может, есть идеи получше.

Comment: Что значит "похожим"?

Comment: Похожий — значит равный исходному, но с некоторым случайным отклонением в каждой точке.

Вначале я создаю набор базовых массивов переменной длины. Потом я получаю некий «похожий» на один из этого набора массив. Мне нужно найти тот, который больше других похож на последний.

Comment: Наверное, нужно было прямо так и сформулировать свой вопрос с самого начала, но я не хотел расширять поле мысли.

Но раз уж я таки объяснил полностью, то хотелось бы заодно узнать, быть может, есть способы и попроще да прогрессивнее? У меня вот есть недочет в виде того, что я буду сравнивать абсолютные значения. Это в некоторых случаях неудобно — из-за возможности накапливания небольших погрешностей в великие. Точнее было бы сравнивать относительные смещения точек (прошу рассматривать массив данных как волну). Есть идея?

Comment: 1) "понижение розрядности" - какая-то нелогичная штука  
2) чтоб не парится касательно размера массивов надо не уменьшать а увиличивать размеры, напр. так: `size = x*y`, где `x,y` - размеры шаблонного и тестируемого массивов  
3) увеличение массива должно быть реализовано дублированием элементов одинаковое количество раз (2...x)  
4) уменьшение массива должно быть реализовано на основе среднего арифметического, таким образом ваш массив на каждой итерации будет терять 1 позицию. если текущей размер больше чем в 2 раза желаемого то сначала надо обработать элементы попарно (1с2, 3с4, ...)

Comment: 5) когда размер будет равный можно будет сравнить схожесть элементов x/p разницу в значениях y[i] = abs (x1[i]-x2[i]), где `x1,x2` - 2 массива. сумма/среднее арифметическое всех y[i] даст вам примерную схожесть всего массива. остется открытым вопрос как трактовать полученый результат, - какая величина приемлимая для схожести массивов можно определить только экспериментально

Comment: 1) В чем нелогична? Я просто заявляю, что погрешность в 5 единиц можно считать незначительной.
2) Спасибо, хорошая идея, однако проблема несоответствия точек (даже смещение точки на одну позицию влево-вправо будет сбоить без сглаживания) так и останется. Попробую как-то это обыграть с простым сглаживанием по среднему.
3) Сделано, но без сглаживания такое преобразование опять же чересчур неточное.
4) --//-- Неточность возрастает. При чем, можно потерять пик, например, в массиве [-100, 100, -100, -100]. Впрочем, я уже нашел решение для этого, но именно сглаживание подводит. Изложу в ответе.

Comment: 5) Я понял, что я не совсем корректно изложил проблему. Мне нужно сопоставление не массивов в прямом понимании, а волн. Используя твой вариант, я не выйду на решение при таких массивах: `[0, 0, 100, 0, 0]` и `[0, 0, 0, 100, 0]`. Опять же, без сглаживания обоих, даже сравнение с учетом погрешности определит, что массивы не похожи. А вот сглаживание привело бы их где-то к виду `[0, 10, 50, 10, 0]` и `[0, 0, 10, 50, 10]` — тут уже можно что-то думать. Пример не лучший, но в большей перспективе (когда длина массива ≈200 вместо 5), это можно заметить.

Comment: @Bars, есть ведь коэффициент корреляции для определения "похожести" и различные методы интерполяции для "сглаживания" и "приведения". Все давно придумано. Рекомендую посмотреть.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Вот [здесь](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CA%EE%F0%F0%E5%EB%FF%F6%E8%FF) есть коэффициент корреляции Пирсона, только там надо добавить индекс, т.е. вместо X читать Xi, вместо Y читать Yi - это элементы двух выборок (массивов). X и Y со штрихами - средние по массивам. Формула легко реализуется циклами - ищем суммы произведений и суммы квадратов, потом вычисляем выражение. НО - массивы должны быть одной длины.

   ```
   // среднее (мат. ожидание)
   double Average(double *p, int n)
   {
       double sum = 0.;
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
           sum += p[i];
       return sum / n;
   }
   // корреляция Пирсона
   double Correl(double *x, double *y, int n)
   {
       double mx = Average(x, n);
       double my = Average(y, n);
       double xx = 0., yy = 0., xy = 0.;
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
       {
           xx += (x[i] - mx) * (x[i] - mx);
           yy += (y[i] - my) * (y[i] - my);
           xy += (x[i] - mx) * (y[i] - my);
       }
       return xy / sqrt(xx * yy);
   }
   ```
2. Если сравниваемые массивы имеют разные длины, то предлагаю растягивать короткий, т.к. при сжатии длинного мы будем терять информацию.
3. Самый простой способ растянуть массив, описывающий некоторый сигнал - [линейная интерполяция](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%cb%e8%ed%e5%e9%ed%e0%ff_%e8%ed%f2%e5%f0%ef%ee%eb%ff%f6%e8%ff). Формулы могут показаться непривлекательными, но суть проста: известны 2 точки, а нам надо найти значение функции (сигнала) где-то между ними. Тогда мы соединяем эти две точки отрезком прямой и находим значение сигнала в требуемой точке между ними. Попробую проиллюстрировать, но считайте это псевдокодом, т.к. не проверял, а просто поясняю идею.

   ```
   // src - исходный (короткий) массив
   // dst - растянутый массив 
   void ExpandArray(double *dst, int dst_len, double *src, int src_len)
   { 
       // важно количество интервалов, а не точек, поэтому "-1."
       double k = (dst_len - 1.) / (src_len - 1.); 
       // расчитываем значения и заполняем массив, кроме крайних элементов
       for (int i = 1; i < dst_len-1; i++) 
       {
           int i1 = i / k;
           // удаленность искомой точки i от существующей точки i1
           double frac = i / k - i1;
           // берем значения соседних точек пропорционально их 1/удаленность от исходной
           dst[i] = src[i1] * (1. - frac) + src[i1 + 1] * frac;
       }
       // крайние точки просто присваиваем, чтобы не помешала погрешность
       // и не выйти за границы массива
       dst[0] = src[0];
       dst[dst_len - 1] = src[src_len - 1];
   }
   ```
4. Если сигналы смещены относительно друг друга на K точек, то можно (самое простое) найти ту же корреляцию, но в отыскивать суммы для i=[1; N-K] и использовать X[i] и Y[i+K]. Или наоборот - смотря какой сигнал смещен.

У корреляции Пирсона есть хорошая черта: если сигналы полностью совпали, она равна 1; если связи нет - 0, если противоположны по знаку - -1.

**UPD:** Код корректен, только в ExpandArray желательно явно привести тип: int i1 = int(i / k);. Собственно корреляция отыскивается легко, добавил в п.1.
И еще вспомнил, что когда-то мне встречалась [такая вот книга](http://mirknig.com/log/full.php?id=1181658354).

Comment: Спасибо, почитал про коэффициент корреляции, сварганил такой вот пример: http://jsfiddle.net/G55aj/2/

Но теперь у меня вопрос: что именно выражает этот коэффициент? Если он сам по себе отражает степень схожести, то что-то не так — посмотрите, как он меняется при инвертировании графиков. На глаз — так и должно быть?

Кроме того, я добавил расчет максимального расхождения (Maximum difference). Возможно, что при использовании сглаживания меня устроит и этот вариант, но разобраться все же хочется.

Спасибо за помощь :)

Comment: Ага, увидел код, сейчас попробую его, спасибо

Comment: Понял, чем ближе к нулю, тем меньше степень схожести (по модулю). Отличный вариант, спасибо большое!

Демо: http://jsfiddle.net/G55aj/4/

Comment: Да, хорошие демки, наглядно )) только у меня обе не показывают значения Maximum difference: и Correlation: почему-то. Я с jsfiddle.net не работал, может что-то надо в смысле настройки?

Comment: Исправил ошибки, которые я не предусмотрел для FF. Вот рабочая версия: http://jsfiddle.net/G55aj/5/

Comment: спасибо, теперь показывает ))

Answer (score 0):

Вот то, что мне удалось сделать: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58L7m/) ([UPD](http://jsfiddle.net/G55aj/))

Здесь описаны 2 функции, которые меня интересуют, но, теоретически не вполне устраивают.

```
function resizeArray(arr, newLength)
    {
    var res = [];
    var k = newLength / arr.length;

    if (k > 1)
        {
        // если растягиваем, то просто просто дублируем соседние точки:
        for (var i = 0; i < newLength; i++)
            res[i] = arr[Math.round(i / k)];
        }
    else
        {
        var value = 0,
            lastJ = 0,
            lastSize = 0;

        // если сжимаем массив, то подставляем среднее арифметическое
        // каждого отрезка:
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            {
            value += arr[i];  // накапливаем значения точек на отрезке
            lastSize++;       // накапливаем количество точек на отрезке
            var j = Math.round(i * k);  // позиция точки в новом массиве
            if (j > lastJ || i == arr.length-1)
                {
                res[lastJ] = value / lastSize;
                value = 0;
                lastSize = 0;
                lastJ++;
                }
            }
        }

    return res;
    }

// -----------------------------------------

function blurArray(arr, blurSize)
    {
    var res = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
        var value = arr[i];  // текущая точка
        var valSides = 0;  // сумма соседних точек

        // суммируем значения соседних точек [-blurSize...+blurSize]:
        for (var j = i - blurSize; j < i + blurSize; j++)
            if (j != i)
                valSides += arr[Math.min(arr.length-1, Math.max(0, j))];

        // «почти среднее» арифметическое:
        res[i] = (value + valSides) / (blurSize * 2);
        }

    return res;
    }
```

Эти решения не устраивают тем, что не позволяют сохранить яркие пики. То есть, при небольших разностях все проходит хорошо, но стоит появиться точке, которая сильно отличается от всех соседних — она слишком подавляется за счет них. Если я правильно воспроизвожу в воображении этот алгоритм Lanczos, то он решил бы мою проблему, но я не понимаю, как его применить.

Comment: > есть ведь коэффициент корреляции для определения "похожести" и различные методы интерполяции для "сглаживания" и "приведения". Все давно придумано. Рекомендую посмотреть.

@paulgri, ну так в этом-то и вопрос. Какие именно и как их применить? В этом я и прошу помощи, не обязательно городить что-то свое. Я сделал свое только потому, что не смог понять чужое.

Comment: @Bars, написал идею в ответе.

Comment: @Bars, функция blurArray реализует т.н. алгоритм цифровой фильтрации методом скользящего среднего, он предназначен как раз для сглаживания пиков, т.е. устранения щелчков, шума и т.п.